# Add to ignore-on-commit list recursively

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnignore

I have a question about ignore-on-commit svn function.

I have directory with sub-folders like

```
C:\path\working_copy\1.config
C:\path\working_copy\subfolder\1.config
```

And when i try to use ignore-on-commit with

```
svn ignore-on-commit C:\path\working_copy\*.config
```

in the ignore list only top level files, and there are no files from subfolder

Can i say "add to the ignore list files *.config recursively"?

`svn cl ignore-on-commit \path\to\working copy\*.config [--recursive]` or something

Please, help. Thanks.